# Partial differentiability with respect to $x$ and $y$ of $\int_0^x z(s,y)ds$ where $\partial_y z \in C^0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I have the following *(not accredited and not mandatory)* Exercise:

> **Problem**: Let $z : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and in respect to its second variable partially differentiable. Define  $$f: \begin{cases} \mathbb{R}^2 & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ (x,y) & \longmapsto \displaystyle \int_0^x z(s,y)ds \end{cases} $$ and show that $f$ is differentiable in respect to $x$ and $y$

I believe I have done 'most of the work' already and confuse myself now in an unnecessary way which is most likely due that this is only my third week in multivariable Calculus and we did not have any helpful theorems yet that I can apply.

---

**Sketch (succeeded, wrt $y$)**: I will only provide a rough sketch of what I did considering partially differentiating $f$ in respect to $y$, because it might be helpful to do the same with respect to $x$ which is where I am stuck.

1) Defined rectangle $R= \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid a \leq x \leq b, \ c \leq y \leq d \rbrace \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

2) Defined mapping $F: [c,d] \to \mathbb{R}, \ y \mapsto \int_0^x z(s,y)ds$ and guessed $F'(y)= \int_0^x \partial_y z(s,y)ds$

3) Computed $ \left|F(y_0+h)-F(y_0)-\left(\int_0^x \partial_yz(s,y)ds\right)h\right|$, which I managed to show is $\leq |h|\epsilon x$ by applying the triangle equality and the mean value theorem, namely $\partial_y z(s, \gamma)h = z(s,y_0+h)-z(s,y_0)$ for $\gamma \in (y_0,y_0+h)$

---

Since this worked out rather nicely I thought I might as well choose the same approach to show that $f$ can be differentiated in respect to $x$, but here I struggle

**My approach (wrt $x$)**: First I defined $$G: \begin{cases}[a,b] & \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ x & \longmapsto \displaystyle \int_0^x z(s,y)ds\end{cases} $$
And my problem now clearly is that although I can guess that $G'(x)=z(x,y)-z(0,y)$ it won't help me applying the definition as above to verify this because I obtain $$ G(x_0+h)-G(x_0)-(z(x,y)-z(0,y))h=\int_0^{x_0+h}z(s,y)ds-\int_0^{x_0}z(s,y)ds-z(x,y)h+z(0,y)h \\ =\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}z(s,y)ds-h(z(x,y)-z(0,y)) $$
which is a rather useless expression.

**Update**: I don't understand how I could implement the fundamental theorem of Calculus into this problem because even if I hold $y$ is constant, I am dealing with  a function that I could differentiate the way as described above, for constant $y$ it would be $G'(x)=z(x,y)$. But if that is the correct derivative, shouldn't I be able to verify it using the definition of a derivative in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you differentiate with respect to $x$, then it all boils down to 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x f(t)\, dt = f(x).
$$
This should be known from Calculus, as long as $f$ is continuous. In your case, $f=z(\#,y)$ for fixed $y$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Siminore. I was thinking of that, and it indeed makes sense to a degree for me, but couldn't I just have made use of the fundamental theorem then when it came to partially differentiating with respect to $y$?

Comment: Absolutely no. The variable $y$ is inside the integrand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, I will brush up a bit on my intuition of the fundamental theorem of Calculus and return to this problem. It makes sense now though!